# Replace data from one csv file to another with search criteria by name with jupyter

Tags: jupyter

i have 2 csv

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\даниил\PycharmProjects\pythonProject/Chelsea.csv', on_bad_lines='skip', names=['Name', 'MP', 'SMP', 'Xg', 'Xa'])
df2 = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\даниил\PycharmProjects\pythonProject/EPLmonster.csv', on_bad_lines='skip')
```

And I need to make sure that first the Name columns are compared, they are the same, and the Price value in one Date frame is substituted from another. Tell me how can I do this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkh08.jpg)

Comment: Now i can use this code

'res = (df1.assign(code=df1["Name"].str.extract(r"\(([^)]*)\)"))
       .merge(df2, how="left"))'